# Anime with special weapons and female characters fighting?

Tags: kampfer

I am trying to find an anime that I had watched years ago. It has these female characters that are trying to fight each other. They have special weapons which they can summon and that I think they wear something that represents their team. They have these toys that help them to have these weapons summoned. I can't seem to remember this anime.

Does anyone know what it might be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The anime that you are trying to find is most likely to be [Kämpfer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4mpfer)

[image]

**Plot:**

> The plot revolves around Natsuru Senō, a normal high school boy with blue hair. One day he wakes up and found himself turned into a girl. A stuffed tiger "Harakiri Tora" comes to life and tells him that he has been chosen as one of the "Kämpfer", a female fighter. The Kämpfer are destined to fight with other Kämpfer. The story starts when he is attacked by an unknown girl who happens to also be a Kämpfer.

Comment: This is it!. Thanks for finding this anime out for me.

Comment: @blobs accpet the answer if it helps you